# Diference between constructor and class members initializing?

Tags: c#, constructor

Whats the difference between using constructor when instantiating with passing arguments:

```
Customer Costomer1 = new Customer(100, Mark, 5000);
```

And doing the same but without passing anything into constructor but simply instantiating members?

```
Customer Costomer1 = new Customer() { ID = 100, Name = "Mark", Salary = 5000, };
```

Which one is better and for what situations are they are good?

Will I be correct if I will say that constructor is when more work needs to be done when instantiating an object and member initializing is for a signing values for fields and properties only?

And if Im understanding this correctly why would you use second case with members if you can use constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is a syntax shortcut(will call default constructor)

```
Customer Costomer1 = new Customer() { ID = 100, Name = "Mark", Salary = 5000, };
```

equals to the follwing

```
Customer Costomer1 = new Customer()
Costomer1.ID = 100;
Costomer1.Name = "Mark";
Costomer1.Salary = 5000;
```

Comment: Marking this as Answer however I'm finding good additional explanation from Robert Harvey, Geek and Serguei Fedorov with some interesting thoughts on this subject.

Answer (score 4):

In the second option, unless you add validation, it is possible to leave out a parameter and have an incomplete instance, whereas in the first option, all parameters are required, so it's not possible to have a partially constructed object.

The second version can be more readable if there are several parameters, although you can use named parameters in the first version if you're using C# 4.

The second version is less work to code, but the first version is easier to get right.

Comment: I think it is also important to note that the syntax with the object initializers is essentially the same as calling the constructor and _then_ setting each property separately on a new LOC. This means the constructor is called before the property assignment, whereas the first method is assigning the property values _within_ the constructor.

Comment: +1. Good note on named parameters - second version is so much easier to get right if constructor ends up something like `MyObject(int row, int column, int count, int depth)` - with sequences of field with the same type.

Answer (score 1):

The first one requires you to have parameters (or optional parameters) in the construction of your object. The second option allows you to initialize the properties of the object as needed.  If you do not require the properties to be initialized then the second option is the better approach.

Answer (score 1):

They both basicaly do the same thing. If you look at it, you always have to call the constructor regardless.

The second one calls the default constructor. It is then responsible for setting up the variables. The first, initializes the variables inside the constructor.

The first is your best and foremost option in any scenario. It is always best to let the object initialize the variables through the constructor. With the second example, the initialization is left to the implementation of the class that created this object, which may not yield the proper results you want from a class.

For instance, in the second example I do:

```
  Customer Costomer1 = new Customer() { Name = "Mark", Salary = 5000, };
```

Now I do not have an ID. The constructor parameters will force the implementer to abide by it's rules. No matter what, you cannot omit the variables passed into the constructor, unless you put in empty variables (ie. "").

Your second example is best when I want to short hand initialize assign variables that are not accepted by the constructor. Basically, as far as I know (I could be terribly wrong), the second does this:

```
   Customer Costomer1 = new Customer();
   Customer1.ID = 100;
   Customer1.Name = "Mark";
   Customer1.Salary = 500;
```

think about the second example as pure short hand.

When constructing a class, you must think about what are the variables that make this class work. For instance, a customer CANNOT not have an ID, though they may not have a defined salary. If I do not include the ID in my customer by mistake, say it is 0, then you can have some very strange behavior as the object get's used.

Consider this scenerio.

```
   Customer Costomer1 = new Customer();
   Customer1.ID = 100;
   Customer1.Name = "Mark";
   Customer1.Salary = 500;

   Customer Costomer2 = new Customer();
   Customer1.Name = "John";
   Customer1.Salary = 500;

   Customer Costomer3 = new Customer();
   Customer1.Name = "Eric";
   Customer1.Salary = 500;
```

now, you have two customers with a 0 for the ID number. While you may by mistake set this to the same value through a constructor, setting the value in the constructor FORCES you to consider the ID number.

The other thing is, when for instance I take your code and I use it for my project. Say I am using your code to extend a program that you have already written. I may may or not be aware of the fact that customers must have ID numbers. Or, more likely, I FORGET to initialize the name and ID number. Your entire system now may exhibit strange behavior as a result.

But speaking purely, out of experience, forcing yourself or your implementer to set certain variables hides the logic into one location. I no longer have to have long strands of code initializing each and every variable that is absolutely necessary for this object. The rule is, normally, that you take any kind of logic that can be repeated and put it into one place.

Last, but not least, you don't usually want to expose writable variables like this. That is, important variables that shouldn't be tampered with. Using a constructor, you can initialize a class with an ID number and hide it inside your class as a private variable. This way, the implementer cannot, by any means, morph the ID number to something else. In my experience this helps to stop people "hot fixing" variables to give them some kind of outcome that they can't figure out how to do normally. This can lead to some very odd behavior in your program.

You can actually have the best of both worlds. Consider this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int someVariable;
    public int someOtherVariable;

    public MyClass(int myVar)
    {
        someVariable = myVar;
    }
}
```

and to initialize:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass(5) { someOtherVariable = 10 };
```

Comment: I would disagree in regards to always setting parameters on construction.  By doing that - if you are doing anything in the constructor with the variables such as setting up state that requires advanced logic that isn't always used -it can be overkill.  You really only need to "require" parameters that are "required" for the object to be used in the most simple scenario.

Comment: @Geek I did this in a bit of a rush. I have updated the code to work properly. As for the initialization of only required variables, you are correct. However, if you want to avoid initializing certain variables, depending on whether you want to used or not, you can overload the constructor. I have worked with a few libraries, cough, EXT.NET, which complain about not set variables all the time because not enough classes override the constructor. If you have a lot of logic that requires "Maybe" will be used, polymorphism works very well to get around this issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean be "polymorphism works very well to get around this issue"?  We are talking about simple construction of a single object - not making multiple types of objects behave the same under certain scenarios.....

Comment: @Geek right. Ok. Why would I have a class that if initialized a certain way, require me to then go back and set variables later? Say I have an object that has Foo() and Bar(). Why would I pass in the variables only necessary for Foo() and not Bar()? What you are talking about is giving more control about the object. For instance when I make a DBConnection object, it's not connected to the DB until I tell it to. This is by situation and will setup internal variables to begin transaction. I shouldn't be passing the connection string into connect(...), as it should already be in the object.

Comment: In other words, any internal variables is it's own internal logic. Anything that needs for my DBConnection to work, should be passed via constructor or else you will end up with a puzzle of variables you need to explicitly set before anything happens.

Comment: What you are describing now is the fundamental difference between properties and internal variables.  Lets take a SqlConnection object.  You have the option to set the connection string on construction - or at a later time.  It is not required until you call an object that initializes the "connection".  If you attempt to do so - you get an exception thrown.  It's also possible under certain conditions that you do not have all the required values at the time of construction.

Comment: Ok, let's take SqlConnection. This object, I hope, manages a single connection to the database. I can route my queries through this object to the database it is meant for. Once I don't need this object, I call close or simply destroy the object to close connection. With the ability to just say "Connect(...)" you start to run into a grey area of making sure this object isn't used to connect to something else. If you have ever worked with a team, you will no doubt know that some bimbo is destined to come along and try something dumb with this function's ability to reconnect to something else.

Comment: I work on a team with close to 100 developer and yes - I agree if you add people to the mix -someone will eventually do something they shouldn't.  This is where process controls, code reviews, and coaching come in to play.  Remember this is software and is created by humans - it will never be perfect - and you can only guard against so much.  When designing a system (even down to the object) you need to keep flexibility in your design.  This is where unit testing and other controls help you do that.

Comment: To be realistic this comes down to the culture of your fellow developers. I tend to be in the atmosphere where people don't read documentation and try to hack their code together (mainly by copy pasta); if there is an easy way to do something, give it to them or there maybe trouble. However if they are willing to dig deeper, I try and still give them them all bells and whistles. On the other hand you seem to come from an atmosphere were conventions and bug tracking are well defined; in addition to people who know what they are doing, so flexibility will not bring the project to a crashing halt